# Valid visa with change in address

Tags: tourist-visas

I have a valid visa in my old passport. However, there's a slight change in my new address. The locality remains the same but the lane is different. Everything else remains the same. Do I need to apply for a new visa or will the old one be valid?

Comment: What kind of visa specifically (name/country)? Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 2):

A visa does not force you to live on a certain address in your home country for extended periods of time. Change of your address in your home country has no bearing on your visa’s validity. Unless you’ve gone broke that is.